# Elixir - Download a File (Image) from a URL

Tags: elixir

What does the code to download a file/image from a URL look like in Elixir?

Google searches seem to bring back how to download Elixir itself.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Have a look at [httpoison](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison), an HTTP client for Elixir. You can just issue a `GET` request to the url pointing to the image (or file, it's irrelevant):

```
%HTTPoison.Response{body: body} = HTTPoison.get!("http://example.com/img.png")
```

`HTTPoison.get!/1` returns an `HTTPoison.Response` struct; I matched on that struct in order to get the body of the response. Now the `body` variables contains the image data (which is just a binary); you can write it to a file:

```
File.write!("/tmp/image.png", body)
```

and there you go :).

<strike>This is obviously possible even without using httpoison, but you would have to deal with raw TCP connections (look at the [`gen_tcp`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html) Erlang module), parsing of the HTTP response and a bunch of stuff you usually don't want to do manually.</strike>

Whoops, forgot to mention the [`httpc`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) Erlang module (included in the stdlib!), which makes this very simple without the need for a dependency like HTTPoison:

```
Application.ensure_all_started :inets

{:ok, resp} = :httpc.request(:get, {'http://example.com/my_image.jpg', []}, [], [body_format: :binary])
{{_, 200, 'OK'}, _headers, body} = resp

File.write!("/tmp/my_image.jpg", body)
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `:httpc`!

Comment: For that to work with https connection use `:ssl.start` after `:inets`

Comment: @denis.pelin and Nomad: Just curious from you own personal experiences if there are any notable differences using HTTPC over HTTPoison?

Answer (score 16):

To stream the URL directly to a file with [httpc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-5):

```
:inets.start()
:ssl.start() 

{:ok, :saved_to_file} = :httpc.request(:get, {'https://elixir-lang.org/images/logo/logo.png', []}, [], [stream: '/tmp/elixir'])
```

I downloaded a 183MB file and the observer showed that memory use never exceeded 25MB. Note the single quoted strings! We cannot pass Elixir strings to this Erlang library.

Comment: In my opinion this should be the accepted answer - it doesn't use external libraries, and it does it in a memory efficient way.

Comment: Important note for the next ones: the single quotes **do** matter in this code: not sure why but apparently this is what Erlang expects. Besides it works really well.

Comment: One more note on the single quotes: if you're working with Elixir strings, just use `String.to_charlist` to convert them to pass to this library.

Comment: Where do I put :inets.start() and :ssl.start() in my project - do I really need to call these every request?

Answer (score 9):

Download method provided by @whatyouhide works but have drawbacks:

- The whole response is loading to the RAM, and only after then is going to the `File.write/1`. You have to choose async HTTPoison request to escape high memory consumption.
- There is no restriction of the file size to download. If you handle, saying, user input and then you're trying to download any file user provided, your server can go down for downloading a file which has 1TB size.

I created [download](https://github.com/asiniy/download) elixir package to bypass these cons.

It has nice syntax and well-tested. Just type

```
Download.from(url, [path: "/where/to/save", max_file_size: integer_in_bytes])
```